# Form element name - array type is not working

Tags: forms

I have a form with multi-select field:

```
<select <?php echo esc_attr($item['pgggo_grid_sort_and_filter_multiselect']);  ?> name="pgggo-taxon-select[]" class="ui fluid dropdown">
```

a foreach loop generates this select field but once the form is submitted, 
the query is a normal variable instead of generating array variables. It generates the query this way:

```
?pgggo-taxon-select%5B%5D=14&pgggo-taxon-select%5B%5D=1
```

Please suggest a solution to have it in array format.

Comment: The form's `method` is likely `GET`, so the `[` and `]` are URL-encoded. But PHP would still treat the input (`$_GET['pgggo-taxon-select']`) as an array.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thhhhhhhhhhhhank You!!!!!!. I was so confused with the URL structure and it's been more than a week! Please make it as an answer. Both get and post method word with `get_query_var` ..get seems to be the common method which adds the query string to the URL ..but post method does not add any query string but I still the required array. Can I use a post ? is it recommended?

Comment: Be careful when using `get_query_var()`, it is not a replacement for retrieving submitted data with `$_POST` or `$_GET`. More on this [in the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/#more-information).

Comment: @CasDekkers hmm if we add "public query variables that are recognized by WP_Query" then it will be all good right?

Comment: Sure, if that's what you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why the `?pgggo-taxon-select%5B%5D=14&pgggo-taxon-select%5B%5D=1` in the URL

There are three common reasons why would one see that upon submitting the form:

1. The form's `method` is `post` (which corresponds to the HTTP POST method) and either:

   a) The current page indeed has that string in the URL. E.g. You're on `example.com/my-page/?pgggo-taxon-select%5B%5D=14&pgggo-taxon-select%5B%5D=1`

   b) The form's `action` has that string. E.g. `<form action="/my-app?pgggo-taxon-select%5B%5D=14&pgggo-taxon-select%5B%5D=1">`
2. Or (most likely in your case), the form's `method` is `get` (which corresponds to the HTTP GET method, and `get` is the default form `method`).

#### Okay, but why not `?pgggo-taxon-select[]=14&pgggo-taxon-select[]=1` ?

Because special characters like square brackets (`[` and `]`) (that have specific meaning) in URLs need to be percent-encoded/URL-encoded (more details on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)); hence, those brackets become `%5B` and `%5D` respectively in the URL — try `urlencode( '[' )` in PHP.

#### So don't worry.. all is good.

PHP would still treat the input (`$_GET['pgggo-taxon-select']`) — when sent as `pgggo-taxon-select%5B%5D` via the GET method — as an array. In fact, PHP (or the server) may not be able to properly parse the input if it was using the unescaped `[` and `]`.

From your comment (formatted for brevity), "*but `post` method does not add any query string but I still get the required array. Can I use a `post` ? Is it recommended?*":

Just use the method that better fits the form's context/purposes — if it's for uploading a file, you should use `post`; if it's just to read/display posts filtered by certain criteria, you can just use `get`.

And these resources would help you understand when to use what HTTP method in submitting a form:

- [HTTP Methods GET vs POST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)
- [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504947)